# How to hide keys which are exposed in decompiled apk through env variables?

Tags: react-native, .env

I'm using `.env` file for storing API keys in react native app, but keys got exposed while decompiling APK file in buildconfig.java file. What are the ways to hide this keys so that in decompiled zip (of apk) will not contain the key names or simply obfuscate the key names so that they aren't exposed directly to any end user?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done, any keys used client side are effectively exposed, client side ENV files are for supporting multiple environments ie dev, staging, prod. most api keys should be used server side, some client side keys ie google maps are configured to be signed with your app or domain